# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end /path/php.module(74)

Tags: php

I'm making a form with CAPTCHA to email me the form.
I made the PHP code but I'm having an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end /path/php.module(74) : eval()'d code on line 103
```

Here is the code:
http://pastebin.com/S2ZvdXTX

Can anyone please tell me what's going on? My eyes are burning out, and can't find that problem, but I know I'm near to it.

BTW, I'm sorry, I'm not a professional with PHP.

Comment: code you posted is being `eval();`ed?

Answer (score 2):

You need an extra `}` at the end.

A `{` must be matched with a `}`.

Comment: can you please show me where is that } i should close – Altin 5 mins ago 
 
I cant find where to put it, if there is no problem paste the code again in pastebin plzz ! – Altin 3 mins ago edit

Comment: @Altin :I've got that in my answer. I think it should be correct

Comment: @Altin: Just add a `}` at the end before the closing PHP tag.

Answer (score 0):

Ya looks like it is just as simple as another } in there.  You never closed the `if` right after that first `else`

Comment: I cant find where to put it,
if there is no problem paste the code again in pastebin plzz !

Comment: plop another bracket in there at line 102

Answer (score 0):

You did not closed your

```
if ($_POST["vercode"] != $_SESSION["vercode"] OR $_SESSION["vercode"]=='')  {
     echo  '<strong>Incorrect verification code.</strong><br>';
} else {
```

(you're missing

```
}
```

at the end)

corrected code
http://pastebin.com/djb8pNQ6

there are also many phpformatters such as http://phpformatter.com which would help

Comment: hello, thank you very much for that but now something else appears

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: vercode in eval() (line 3 of /var/www/drupal/modules/php/php.module(74) : eval()'d code).
Notice: Undefined index: vercode in eval() (line 3 of /var/www/drupal/modules/php/php.module(74) : eval()'d code).

Comment: when
wihout captcha i have two lines of this
Notice: Undefined index: vercode in eval() (line 3 of /var/www/drupal.flossk.org/modules/php/php.module(74) : eval()'d code).

with captcha correct I still have:
Notice: Undefined index: vercode in eval() (line 3 of /var/www/drupal/modules/php/php.module(74) : eval()'d code).
and the email doesnt go

Answer (score 0):

sometime this occours due to missing '{}' .
for this you only have to thoroughly chech the code up to downward.